# pymysql видит user, но не выполняется условие

Tags: python, pymysql

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(user = "root",password = "",host = "127.0.0.1",database = "users")
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM login")

rows = cursor.fetchall()

for loop in rows:
    if loop == "cgduude":
        print("nashel")
    print(loop)

conn.commit()
```

При выводе всех элементов БД в консоль вывод ('cgduude',),но условие не выполняется

Answer (score 1):

надо искать именно в столбцах

```
for loop in rows:
    if loop[0] == "cgduude":
        print("nashel")
    print(loop)
```